# Notes Client doesn't show Actions menu

Tags: menu, hcl-notes

I'm an HCL Notes developer. I have recently installed Notes client 10. But I can't see lots of menu options from within client including Actions menu. Other menus also provide limited sub-menu options. Please help on from where i can configure to show/hide menu options.

[image]

Comment: Do i have to configure some parameter in notes.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got the solution by googling this "how to configure notes.ini to show/hide menu items". Added the line

AdvProp_MenuVisible=1 at the end of my notes.ini file.

The link is below for the help to any else who's looking for the same issue.

https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/beta/12.0.1/conf_controllingadvancedpropertiesmenus.html